# Update form data with image in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multipartform-data

Hi in my application there is add and update the form where it consists of some text fields and image upload also, Adding the image using formData is working and able to add record successfully, While updating the same record  i am getting the image Url from Api, and without editing the image i am trying to update the record and it is not working getting 400 bad request, Below is the code:

```
const formData = new FormData();
    
    formData.append("images", uploadProps);
    formData.append("name", data.name);
    formData.append("location", data.location);
    formData.append("theme", data.theme);
```

followed by api call.

```
 uploadProps is the imageUrl:"https://dev-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/images/79045f8b-1aa4-4e11-8fac-9532b3564e53.png"
**imageurl is dummy url
```

If i select any image while updating it is working fine.